# What happens when a char array is initialized to '\0'?

Tags: c

I have a char array of size 512 i.e

```
char buffer [512];
```

This variable after some point is modified to this

```
buffer [40] = '\0';
```

What does this assignment does to the variable? Does it initialize the first 40 char in the array to null?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It assigns **only** the 41st char in the array to `\0`. Thus now *the string* consists of what the chars represent in the first 40 elements of the array  i.e 0 to 39th indices (assuming there were no other `NUL` characters in any of the previous elements -Thanks  Kerrek SB!!) .
Hope this helps!

Comment: Well, "at most" in the first 40 characters. There might be another zero earlier on.

Comment: Thanks KerrekSB and @another.anon.coward - very helpful answer, so nowthe buffer values is restricted to first 40 char(assuming no other null char in between).

Answer (score 5):

No.   It stores the value NUL at the 41st position in the array.

To init the first 40 characters to NUL

```
memset(buffer, '\0', 40);
```

To init the entire buffer to NUL at compile time, try

```
char buffer[512] = {0};
```

or

```
char buffer[512] = "";
```

To init it at run time, try

```
memset(buffer, '\0', sizeof (buffer));
```

Answer (score 1):

It assigns the character `'\0'` (i.e. the `NUL` character) to the 41st array element.